# java.io.PrintWriter +print(cArray: char[] ): void

Tags: java, arrays, exception, printing

I don't know how to write this line: `+print(cArray: char[]): void` . I know what I want to do for my homework problem, it's just this array line that the book did a lousy job explaining. If you want to know the problem: Write a program to create a file named `Excercise12_15.tx` if it does not exist. *Write 100 integers* created randomly into the file using the test I/O. Integers are seperated by spaces in the file. Read the data back from the file and display the data in increasing order.

```
package WriteReadData;

import java.util.*;
public class WriteReadData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Excercise12_15.txt");
        final int SIZE = 100;
        int [] emptyArray = new int[SIZE];

        if ( file.exists())
        {
            System.out.print("File exists");
            System.exit(0);
        }//end if 

        try 
        {
            java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

            for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
            emptyArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            output.print(emptyArray: int[]): void 
            }//end for 

        }//end try 
        catch 
        {
            output.close();
        }//end catch 
    }//end main 
}//end class
```

Comment: This program isn't finished of course, I just need my question answered to be nudged in the right direction.

Comment: You are having an issue printing the array to the text file?

Comment: Don't place output.close() in the catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/Users/someUser/Desktop/Excercise12_15.txt");
    final int SIZE = 100;
    int [] emptyArray = new int[SIZE];

    if ( file.exists())
    {
        System.out.print("File exists");
        System.exit(0);
    }//end if 

//Place your output variable up here, so that it could be seen in the catch and finally block.

    java.io.PrintWriter output = null;
    try 
    {
        output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

        for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            emptyArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            //Your issuse was here, you didn't write the array to the file correctly
            output.print(emptyArray[i] + " "); 
        }//end for 

    }//end try 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }//end catch
    finally{
        //Don't place the close in the catch block, do it in the finally, because it always
        //executes even when a catch happens.
         output.close();
    }

}
```

This is how to properly write the array to a text file with spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But why does the book list the example as:  +print(cArray: char[]): void ? (Introduction to Java 10th edition, Daniel Liang).

Comment: @Doug099 - Terribly Sorry, but I don't have that book. Maybe an error, check the official site for any errors .